# Separate JSON result into variables

Tags: php, json

I have the following generated JSON result and would like to find out how I can separate the results into 2 variables:

JSON

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "source": "server1",
                "host": "pc1",
                "description": "SSH server is down on {HOSTNAME}",
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "source": "server2",
                "host": "pc2",
                "description": "webapp down",
            }
        ]
    ],
    "error": {
        "server3": "Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server",
        "server4": "Can't connect to MySQL server",
    }
}
```

Intended Result:

```
{
    "data": [
            {
                "source": "server1",
                "host": "pc1",
                "description": "SSH server is down on {HOSTNAME}",
            },
            {
                "source": "server2",
                "host": "pc2",
                "description": "webapp down",
            }
        ]
}
```

And

```
{
    "error": {
        "server3": "Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server",
        "server4": "Can't connect to MySQL server",
    }
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  include '../include/db_conn.php';
  print to_json(get_all_alert());
 $return = get_all_alert();
print to_json($return["data"]);
print to_json($return["error"]);
?>
```

The php code still prints the results combined twice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your json data is not correct you can check here:http://json.parser.online.fr/
remove extra commas from each array part.

try this:

```
<?php
$data1='{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "source": "server1",
                "host": "pc1",
                "description": "SSH server is down on {HOSTNAME}"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "source": "server2",
                "host": "pc2",
                "description": "webapp down"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "error": {
        "server3": "Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server",
        "server4": "Cant connect to MySQL server"
    }
}';

$val_array = json_decode($data1,true);

print_r($val_array['data']);
print_r($val_array['error']);
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to use your answer to correct the error and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got an extra line you probably don't need.

`print to_json(get_all_alert());`

Remove that, and your problem is likely to go away.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but still have one issue. The json format isn't still OK